# How can the manufacturer of this faucet be identified?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink

My bathroom sink faucet is leaking water.  It appears that the water is seeping out at the stem cartridge.  I'd like to just order a single cartridge to repair it, but I can't figure out the manufacturer. Would it be possible to identify it from the photos I'm providing?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might just be faster to take the cartridge to a plumbing store/shop.  Turn off the water first.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll try that.